# Old QHD iMac (2009~) as an external monitor for macbook pro 16 inches - bad idea?

Tags: display, imac

I was going to get a QHD monitor for MacBook pro 16 inches
and settled on Dell S2719DM for its price (roughly 420 dollars from where I live).

And then I thought that it might be better, price-wise, to get a cheap, old, and second-handed QHD iMac (starting from late 2009). Same resolution, cheaper and with a bit of risk for being used for a long time.

Am I missing some important detail? They sell mini display port to usb-c converter, but will it work as expected?

Comment: Did you consider running cost?  Late 2009 iMac [uses](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201918) 145-365W, while [S2719DM](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-27-ultrathin-monitor-s2719dm/apd/210-anyx/monitors-monitor-accessories) uses 29-42W and only 0.3W on standby.  Obviously you don't have to wait for the Dell to boot up macOS before you use it so you'd perhaps be more likely to turn it off more often...

Comment: @lx07 That’s a huge difference that I have completely overlooked. Also I just assumed it would be plug and go with no booting. Thanks.